Difference between "Who are you?" VS "Who is yourself?"
This is from the BBC, in which human's obssession with afterlife is questioned and scrutinized. At one point, there is this sentence:

"... It comes down to how you define who you are. What are you? Who is yourself?..." BBC-why are humans obsessed with the afterlife (see:5:06-5:12)

The question "Who is yourself" has caught my attention, because simply you would expect that the question "What are you?" is to be followed by "Who are you?". So instead of saying "Who are you?", the question is formed in a different structure "Who is yourself?"
I have been thinking about it, and the only reason I could think of is that maybe the question "Who is yourself?" regards a humanbeing as a non-physical entity rather than a physical/worldly one?
Did I get it right?

No - Who is yourself? is very strange phrasing, to  say the least. In context, I can only assume it's equivalent to something like What is the "self" that make you you? But it's stretching English to the limit and beyond. You won't learn anything from it.

Note that immediately after this sentence, the speaker is talking about different types of "self" that he gives names like "mem-self" and "POV-self" (these are his own terms, not standard ones). He is probably saying "yourself" to set up the idea that he's talking about selfhood in general.

It is not strange phrasing in this context. The trick is to understand how the speaker got there. Me, myself, I think it's right. Another person says to me: Yeah, who's me? Who's myself? Here, the speaker has just made two utterances instead of one: Who is you, yourself? appositively.

it's  not yourself   ... it is your self

@jsotola Yeah, that's a pretty obvious typo there. Curse you autocorrect!

Who is your self? Is not great.

No, it is emphatic. Better phrasing would have been: Who are you, yourself?
But the speaker breaks it into two utterances: What are you? Who is yourself? It's fine. It's a re-iteration.
In the context of discussing the afterlife, it's works fine.

Note that even "who are yourself" is also completely non-idiomatic. It's the "yourself" that is the problem, not the chosen verb.

@SoronelHaetir Once again, in "Who are you, yourself?",  you and yourself are appositives. There is no: Who are yourself? "Who is yourself" is idiomatic. Yourself is a pronoun.

According to OP, the first utterance was "What are you?" not "Who are you?"
